# Minor iPhone Layout Issue

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

When viewing your own profile from an iPhone in Safari, there appears to be an overlapping element which covers part of the avatar. This doesn't happen when viewing someone else's profile. Yes, small issue, but an issue none-the-less.

I'm using iOS 4.3.5 on an iPhone 4.

[image: iPhone Layout issue]

Comment: You mean the missing spaces in StackOverflow and StackExchange? ;-)

Comment: Wondering how long it will take before someone says "Why is your search engine set to Bing?"

Comment: Biggest.  Iphone.  Ever.

Comment: I've seen this once or twice. it went away when I refreshed the page. But this isn't something I can repro on purpose.

Comment: @Jin - Interesting. I can reliably reproduce this, but the more I play with it the more I think it's a Safari rendering issue. Doing anything on the page, even scrolling, makes it go away.

Comment: If you touch and hold the image you'll a Copy option. Next, paste the copied URL into Safari's location bar. Has it the same issue? (Note that the image on your profile has a different size, and hence a different URL than the avatars used next to your posts. Maybe that larger image is cached somehow faulty. Though that would not explain that things are fine after you scroll.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue, either simulated or on actual hardware.

Comment: Hm, odd. I can consistently reproduce it for my profile on different devices. If it's just me - then that's OK then.